# execution time work sharing vs spmd

Tags: openmp

I'm writing two similar programs to compare the execution time in spmd vs. worsharing.
To my surprise I'm getting more execution time in work sharing while time in spmd is considerably less.

What did I do wrong to get that?

Here are my codes:

SPMD code:

```c
#define N 1000
float A[N][N], B[N][N], C[N][N]; // declaring matrices of NxN size
int main() {
    /* DECLARING VARIABLES */
    int i, j, k; // indices for matrix multiplication

    /* FILLING MATRICES WITH RANDOM NUMBERS */
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
            A[i][j]= (rand()%10);
            B[i][j]= (rand()%10);
        }
    }
    /* MATRIX MULTIPLICATION */
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    int id;
    int m;
    int nthrds;  
    #pragma omp parallel // num_threads(4)
    {
        id=omp_get_thread_num();
        nthrds=omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("number of threads %d",nthrds);
        double wtime = omp_get_wtime();
        for (i=id;i<N;i=i+nthrds) {
            //dummy=i+nthrds;
            for(j=id;j<N;j=j+nthrds) {
                C[i][j]=0;
                for(k=id;k<N;k=k+nthrds) {
                    C[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];
                }
                // printf("%d ", C[i][j]);  
            }
            //printf("\n");
        }

        wtime = omp_get_wtime() - wtime;
        printf( "Time taken  is %f\n", wtime );
        getchar(); 
    }
}
```

the work sharing code is :

```c
.......
int main() {
    /* DECLARING VARIABLES */
    int i, j, k; // indices for matrix multiplication

    /* FILLING MATRICES WITH RANDOM NUMBERS */
    srand ( time(NULL) );
    for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
            A[i][j]= (rand()%10);
            B[i][j]= (rand()%10);
        }
    }
    /* MATRIX MULTIPLICATION */
    //printf("Max number of threads: %i \n",omp_get_max_threads()); 

    double wtime = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel private(j,k) num_threads(8)
    {   
        #pragma omp for 
        for (i=0;i<N;i++) {
            for(j=0;j<N;j++) {
                C[i][j]=0;
                for(k=0;k<N;k++) {
                    C[i][j]+=A[i][k]*B[k][j];
                } 
                // printf("%d ", C[i][j]);  
            }
            //printf("\n");
        }
        double etime = omp_get_wtime() - wtime;
        printf( "Time taken  is %f\n", etime );
        getchar(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: In your 'SPMD' version, only the 1st loop (in `i`) should be incremented by steps of `nthreads`, not the 2 innermost ones (in `j` and `k`).

Comment: OK it means that its only the outer most loop that divides the tasks into threads?